# How to assign one strict datatype variable value using another variable in angular?

Tags: angular, types, declare

I am an Angular Developer and working on one project in which I used strict DataType and define variable with my custom DataType Like this :

```
Code: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 = 1;
```

Here above variable declaration **will work perfect** if we assign this `code` variable with constant value directly. like this :

```
Code = 3;
```

But this **will give an Error** if I try to assign it using a variable like this :

```
let num = this.getNumberBewteen1_5();
Code = num;
```

and function `getNumberBewteen1_5()` is the function which return one number between 1 and 5 ;

Is there any way to fix it without remove strict `DataType` in angular ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that method returned type should be the same as variable type.
You try to assign number to 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 which is different type.

Working example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

type YourType = 1 | 2 | 3;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  a: YourType;

  constructor() {
    let b = this.yourMethod();
    this.a = b;
  }

  yourMethod(): YourType { // returned type is YourType (not number)
    return 1; // or 2 | 3
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help me buddy, I appreciate your Answer. one more thing, Suppose if I perform operation on number to return value from function then will it work ?

Comment: Suppose, in `yourMethod()` function, if I perform like this : `if(number > 5) { return 1} else { return number++; }`

Will this function work ? It seems that this will not work...

Comment: It will work if you do `return number++ as YourType;`